# VSTS Extension: Initialize or create a master branch from a new repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to use the Visual Studio Team Services REST API to init a newly created repository?

Comment: There has no such REST API to initialize new created repo. But there has other options to intialize a created repo. I updated the details in my answer, and you can have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant believe i missed this from the VSTS REST api documentation, but here is how you can create and init a new git repository on vsts and also tested it with TFS 2015 on-prem

Createing a new repository:

Post: http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=3.0

Body:

```
{
  "name": "AnotherRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "e7154789-27db-4ee5-a192-4d69594c6588"
  }
}
```

Initializing the new repository:

Post: http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/4968177d-1f0b-4009-a635-272af892f536/pushes?api-version=3

Body:

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Initial commit.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/readme.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "My first file!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

VSTS REST Documentation:

- Creating Repo:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1
- Init Repo:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pushes/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1#initial_commit_(create_a_new_branch)

Comment: You can mark your own answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.